# spatial domain convolution not equal to frequency domain multiplication using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, fft, convolution

I want to verify if 2D convolution in spatial domain is really a multiplication in frequency domain, so I used pytorch to implement convolution of an image with a 3×3 kernel (both real). Then I transformed both the image and the kernel into frequency domain, multiplied them, transformed the result back to spatial domain. Here's the result:
When the kernal is even or odd (i.e. pure real or pure imaginary in frequency domain), results of the two transforms seem to match well. I use min and max of both results to evaluate because I'm not sure if some margin alignment problems may affect direct difference. Here are three runs of either even and odd kernel:

```
# Even Kernel
min max with s-domain conv: -0.03659552335739136 4.378755569458008
min max with f-domain mul: -0.0365956649184227 4.378755569458008

min max with s-domain conv: -1.2673343420028687 2.397951126098633
min max with f-domain mul: -1.2673344612121582 2.397951126098633

min max with s-domain conv: -8.185677528381348 0.22980886697769165
min max with f-domain mul: -8.185677528381348 0.22980868816375732

# Odd Kernel
min max with s-domain conv: -1.6630988121032715 1.6592578887939453
min max with f-domain mul: -1.663098692893982 1.6592577695846558

min max with s-domain conv: -3.483165979385376 3.4751217365264893
min max with f-domain mul: -3.483165979385376 3.475121259689331

min max with s-domain conv: -1.7972984313964844 1.7931475639343262
min max with f-domain mul: -1.7972984313964844 1.7931475639343262
```

But if I use neither even or odd kernel, the difference is just at another level:

```
min max with s-domain conv: -2.3028392791748047 1.675748348236084
min max with f-domain mul: -2.5289478302001953 1.4919483661651611

min max with s-domain conv: -1.1227827072143555 3.0336122512817383
min max with f-domain mul: -1.1954418420791626 2.9853036403656006

min max with s-domain conv: -1.6867876052856445 5.575590133666992
min max with f-domain mul: -1.6832940578460693 5.688591957092285
```

I was wondering if this arises from precision in floating point. But I tried torch's complex128, it wasn't any better. Is there something wrong with my implementation? Or it is inevitable due to calculation with complex numbers?

Here's a simplified version of my code that could produce this result.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.fft as fft
import torch, cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.png', 0)

x = torch.as_tensor(img).unsqueeze(0)/255
k = torch.randn(1, 1, 3, 3)
for i in range(k.size(0)):
    for j in range(k.size(1)):
        # For even k
        # for p in range(k.size(2)):
            # for q in range(k.size(3)):
                # k[i, j, p, q] = k[i, j, 2-p, 2-q]
        # For odd k
        # for p in range(k.size(2)):
            # k[i, j, p, 0] = -k[i, j, p, 2]
            # k[i, j, p, 1] = 0
        # for q in range(k.size(3)):
            # k[i, j, 0, q] = -k[i, j, 2, q]
            # k[i, j, 1, q] = 0
        pass

### Spatial domain convolution
padx = F.pad(x, [1,1,1,1])
sdc = F.conv2d(padx.unsqueeze(0), k)

### Frequency domain convolution
# Transform input
fdx = fft.rfft2(x)
sdfdx = fft.irfft2(fdx)

# Transform kernel
size_diff = x.size(-1)-k.size(-1)
padk = torch.roll(F.pad(k, [0,size_diff,0,size_diff]), (-1,-1), (-1, -2))
fdk = fft.rfft2(padk)

# Frequency domain multiplication
fdc = fdk * fdx
fdc = fdc.squeeze(0)

# Back to spatial domain
sdfdc = fft.irfft2(fdc)

### Compare
print("min max with s-domain conv:", sdc.min().item(), sdc.max().item())
print("min max with f-domain mul:", sdfdc.min().item(), sdfdc.max().item())
```

Comment: This is likely a problem with the location of the origin in the padded kernel. The origin must be in the top-left pixel, otherwise you’ll shift the output image.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but it is better than no guess.

Try transposing your filter before convolving.

Because you know the math, convolving without filter transpose is really a correlation, so you do filter transpose to make that correlation into the actual convolution.